# Pandas - Extracting specific text after a common word

Tags: regex, pandas

I have some sales data that has customer wise data. All purchases made by a customer is all stored in a single row as shown below. I am trying to create a new column wherein all products purchased by each customer is listed in a single row separated by a comma

```
id, value
101, day:day_1\nproducts:abc\nday:day_2\nproducts:xyz\nday:day_3\nproducts:def
102, day:day_1\nproducts:prod_1\nday:day_4\nproducts:prod_2
103, \n
```

Trying to convert the above data into the below format:

```
id,value
101,abc,xyz,def
102,prod_1,prod_2
103,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) with [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df['value'] = df['value'].str.findall('products:(.+)').str.join(',')
print (df)
    id          value
0  101    abc,xyz,def
1  102  prod_1,prod_2
2  103
```

Or solution with `split` in list comprehension:

```
L = [','.join(y.split(":")[1] for y in v.split("\n") if ('products' in y))
     if pd.notna(v) and (':' in v) and ('\n' in v) 
     else ''
     for v in df['value']]

df1 = df[['id']].join(pd.DataFrame(L, index=df.index, columns=['value']))
print (df1)
    id          value
0  101    abc,xyz,def
1  102  prod_1,prod_2
2  103
```